# Read string before '@' in URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

I recently saw that https://appetize.io/docs#request-api-token takes advantage of the space in a URL before the '@' sign (e.g. API-TOKEN@api.appetize.io). Is it possible to fetch that string before the '@' sign  using PHP or the .htaccess?

Comment: So you mean you want to get API-TOKEN?

Comment: @RaxWeber No I was just using that as an example. I just want to get whatever is in front of the '@' sign.

Comment: If you have alittle bit more complicated URL like `http://something:API-TOKEN@api.appetize.io`, do you still want to get only `API-TOKEN` or `http://something:API-TOKEN`?

Comment: *Everything* before the @ sign in a URL will get you the scheme, username and password as a single string, which doesn't sound very useful. If you're trying to parse a single part of a URL, use `parse_url`, which exists for this purpose.

Answer (score -1):

You can parse it by using `explode()`.

```
if (strpos($your_url, '@') !== false)
{
    $result = explode("@", $your_url)[0];
}
```

Comment: That would give incorrect value when there's no `@` in the url.

Answer (score -1):

This part of the URL is called `username`, because it can be used used in urls containing authentication data like:

```
https://username:password@example.com
```

You can use `parse_url()` function which will do the job for you:

```
$url = 'https://API-TOKEN@api.appetize.io';    
$apiToken = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_USER);    
var_dump($apiToken); // string(9) "API-TOKEN"
```

https://3v4l.org/hgM2i